# Write to a variable from DSC script resource

Tags: powershell, dsc

Is it possible to write to external variable from DSC "script" resource? To pass it through different script resources?
Example:

```
Configuration SomeConfiguration 
{
   $list = @()

   Script SomeScript 
   {
      TestScript = {
         $using:list += "1"
         $using:list += "2"

         return $false
      }  
      SetScript = {
         $using:list | Foreach-Object {
            ...
         }
      }
      GetScript = { }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Before executing every Test/Set function the LCM resets the state of the Runspace - i.e all variables are cleared. Therefore if you want to pass information, the best way is to write to a file and read from it